# Find valid nodes in a grid based on a X range

Tags: javascript, coordinates, nodes, a-star, breadth-first-search

I'm having a problem with finding N positions in a grid based on a central point and a max range.

I have this grid, each coordinate in the grid can be either closed or open, I'm tying to, using an open coordinate, find all the open coordinates around the first that are valid and the walk range between then is equal or lower than the max walk range.

At first I tried a solution using A*, where I would select every coordinate in range, check if they were valid, if they were I would call A* from them to the center position and count the number of steps, if they were higher than my max range I would just remove the coordinate from my list. Of course, this is really is slow for ranges higher than 3, or grids with more than just a few coordinates.
Then I tried recursively searching for the coordinates, starting with the central one, expanding and recursively checking for the coordinates validness. That solution proved to be the most effective, except that in my code, each function call was rechecking coordinates that were already checked and returning repeated values. I thought I could just share the 'checked' list between the functions calls, but that just broke my code, since a call was checking a coordinate and closing it even if it still had child nodes but were technically not in range of their center (but were in range of the first center) it would close them and give some weird results.

Finally, my question is, how do I do that? Is my approach wrong? Is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented something similar once. The simple recursive solution you proposed worked fine for small walk ranges, but execution time spun out of control for larger values ...

I improved this by implementing a variant of Dijkstra's algorithm, which keeps a list of visited nodes as you said. But instead of running a full path search for every coordinate in reach like you did with A*, do the first N iterations of the algorithm if N is your walk range (the gif on Wikipedia might help you understand what I mean). Your list of visited nodes will then be the reachable tiles you're looking for.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: That worked! It was a bit of a pain to implement it right, but in the end that was the best solution. Thanks :)